# Pass Data from the TabBarController to child view controllers on initial load

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a Tab Bar Controller and two linked child view controllers connected to it.

However I need to pass values from the TabBarController to the children right when the tabs are loaded for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `viewDidLoad` of the custom tab class do

```
let vc = self.viewControllers.last! as! SecondVC 
vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
vc.somePro = <#value#>
```

Comment: is there a viewControllers.second or third?

Comment: only `first` and `last` and for intermidate use index `viewControllers[1]`

Comment: I need to do the same for all 3 of my views